# Make a scollable div fill remaining space

Tags: html, css

I want to display all products on the left side of the website.

[image: Sketch].

But I can't manage to make the middle part (1) scrollable and (2) fill the whole space between the search bar and the button at the bottom.
Setting a height makes the whole thing scrollable, but if I try to fit it to fill the space the scrolling disappears and you can't access the bottom products.
Thank you for helping

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.main-container {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.left-row {
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.border-top {
  height: fit-content;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.products {
  border: none;
}

.add {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  width: 20%;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
}

.card {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.card-body .card-body {
  height: 100px;
}

.hover:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main-container d-flex flex-row">
    <div class="left-row d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="input-group justify-content-center p-3">
        <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
      </div>

      <div class="border-top">
        <div class="products card-body">
          @foreach (Product product in Model.products) {
          <div class="card hover" style="display: flex">
            <p>product</p>
          </div>
          }
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="add fixed-bottom d-flex justify-content-center">
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Add</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `.border-top { height: fit-content;` ? Don't ever mix Duplos with Legos

Comment: try `overflow: auto`

Comment: `<a type="button"` should be `<button type="button"` - and yes, always use Buttons if you don't need Anchors.

Answer (score 1):

I removed all your classes because I'm not sure if they're related to some library or not. So just to simplify it all I tried to use mostly `.row` and `.col`, and a `.max` to simply `flex: 1;` where needed

```css
/*QuickReset*/ *, *::before, *::after {margin:0; box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.row, .col { display: flex; }
.row { width: 100%; }
.col { flex-direction: column; }
.max { flex: 1; }
.clip { overflow: auto; }

/* Other app styles */

aside { width: 20%; }
aside input, aside .btn { width: 100%; }
main { background: #ddd; }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col">

    <div>
      <input type="search" placeholder="Search..."/>
    </div>

    <div class="max clip">
      <p style="height: 300vh;">Tall paragraph to force some scrollbars</p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button type="button" class="btn">Add</button>
    </div>

  </aside>

  <main class="max">
    App goes here
  </main>

</div>
```